# Issue in performance in Subsonic 3.0.0.4

Tags: .net, database, subsonic, subsonic3

We have a performance issue with subsonic and I think we might be doing something wrong.

**From Subsonic 1.0.3**

```
CustomerCollection rc = new CustomerCollection();
rc.LoadAndCloseReader(
    SPs.UspLoadCustomers(
        dtToday.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        dtToday.Date.AddDays(intDays).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        intCompanyId.ToString()
    ).GetReader()
);
return rc
```

**From Subsonic 3.0.0.4**

```
CustomerDB cmDB = new CustomerDB();

return cmDB.usp_LoadCustomers(
        dtToday.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        dtToday.Date.AddDays(intDays).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        intCompanyId.ToString()
    ).ExecuteTypedList<Customer>();
```

Now, the previous version of subsonic took around 1.046 (3 occurance) seconds and latest version is taking 3.095 (3 occurance) seconds.

We have checked this many times and the result is the same. Can we improve the performance by changing any part of the code ?

Comment: not an answer to this particular question, but of all the orms I measured subsonic seemed slowest http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Comment: Might be that is true. But it specifically shown from version 1.0.3 to 3.0.0.4. That is bit strange. So Sam what do you suggest if we are using subsonic in our project and want to quickly migrate to other orm. Is petapoco okay for this?

Comment: .. I can not answer that question cause I have no idea how big or complex your project is, nor do I know your performance requirements .. you may be able to structure stuff in such a way that a micro orm takes care of performance critical parts ... I don't know